# real time remaining time with javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, clock

I want to show remaining time inside a foreach loop. I want to show difference between `activationEndTime` column and current time in database;

this code is not working well for me what should I do?

```js
(function() {
  const second = 1000,
    minute = second * 60,
    hour = minute * 60,
    day = hour * 24
  let myTime = '<?= $key->activationEndTime?>'
  countDown = new Date(myTime).getTime(),
    x = setInterval(function() {
      let now = new Date().getTime(),
        fark = countDown - now;
      document.getElementById("minutesx").innerText = Math.floor((fark % hour) / minute);
      if (0 >= fark) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("countdown-Key").innerHTML = '<span>Süre Doldu</span>'
      }
    }, 0)
}());
```

```html
<div class="sverification-inner" id="countdown-Key">
  <ul style="text-align: center">
    <li>
      <span id="minutesx" class="timers"></span>
      <span class="times">DAKİKA</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please replace `'<?= $key->activationEndTime?>'` with a proper time to make a [mcve]

Comment: thanks i will be more careful

Comment: It's okay when I export it statically. `let myTime='2022-07-21 20:35:07'` but how do i do it dynamically

Comment: What do you mean? Using Ajax?

Comment: I'm not using ajax I want to return the date value inside the loop and it's confusing

Comment: You cannot access the PHP date element in the script without Ajax. It is rendered as the page loads

Comment: I not need ajax, I couldn't explain my problem, I guess it works when I type a date statically, but `'<?= $key->activationEndTime?>'` data is not working even though it is correct

Comment: View source and see how it looks

Comment: does your javascript file that contains the `<?= $key->activationEndTime ?>` end with the file extension .php? if not, your server may not be set up to preprocess it using PHP.  How does the `$key` variable get populated even if this were processed by PHP? Typically you would not process javascript files with PHP, but rather use PHP to put variable values into your HTML tag attributes, and use javascript to grab those values, or if you need those variables dynamically, you would use AJAX to request PHP data from the server using your javascript when needed.

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` would be much more efficient as `Date.now()`.